# How to copy a file from one folder to other in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a site, i want copy a file in programmatic way from local machine to server machine in c#. can any one please help to do that.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

Use the [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control.

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons, you cannot use access the client's filesystem from the server.

All you can do is ask the user to upload a file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy a file from the host the app/site is running on to a different host and use FTP you can do this with FtpWebRequest like explained [HERE](http://www.logiclabz.com/c/ftp-file-upload-using-ftpwebrequest-in-net-c.aspx).
If you want your user to upload a file to the server use the [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control like Uwe suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
File.Copy(source, destination);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tried your method, it works fine while running in local. But when i move and execute in server. it showing file doesn't exist as exception.

Comment: that means it either doesn't exist or you don't have permissions to access the folder.

Comment: but that file is existing in local machine

Comment: it must be a permission problem then